# Cypress wait is yielding the same URL twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have a an webapp and I'm currently writing Cypress tests for it. I recently upgraded to version 6.0, that includes the new `cy.intercept()` method, that replaces the `cy.route()` method. However, I'm having trouble with the usage because of inconsistencies in tests results.

On my page, when a specific input is blurred, it sends a request to my api with it's value the deduce a result from it.

This test is written to write a first text in the input, blur the focus, clear the input and then write another text and blur the focus. I should then have 2 API calls going, but in my second wait, the job name is wrong, because the url is still the url of the first call.

However, if I remove the first `cy.wait()`, I get the correct url in the second call. Sometimes the tests pass, but if I launch the test again, they fail.

Am I missing something ?

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/page');
  cy.intercept(
    'GET',
    'https://my.api/jobs'
  ).as('sendJobName');
});  

it('...', () => {
      cy.getBySelector('myInput')
        .type('Job name 1')
        .focus()
        .blur({ force: true })
        .clear();

      cy.wait('@sendJobName').then((interception) => {
        const { url } = interception.request;
        const { statusCode, body } = interception.response;

        expect(url)
          .to.be.a('string', 'url should be a string')
          .and.satisfy(
            (url: string) =>
              url.endsWith(encodeURIComponent('Job name 1')),
            'url should end with the right job'
          );
        expect(statusCode, 'first status should be 200').to.equal(200);
        expect(
          body,
          'first body should correspond to first request'
        ).to.deep.equal([...]);
      });

      // Type a second valid job name
      cy.getBySelector('myInput')
        .type('Job name 2', { force: true })
        .focus()
        .blur({ force: true });

      cy.wait('@sendJobName').then((interception) => {
        const { url } = interception.request;
        const { statusCode, body } = interception.response;

        expect(url)
          .to.be.a('string', 'url should be a string')
          .and.satisfy(
            (url: string) => url.endsWith(encodeURIComponent('Job name 2')),
            'url should end with the right job'
          ); // This assertion fails
        expect(statusCode, 'second status should be 200').to.equal(200);
        expect(
          body,
          'second body should correspond to second request'
        ).to.deep.equal([...]);
      });
    });
```

Comment: If the input text is sent as a query addition to the base URL, you can use a variant of [routematcher](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#routeMatcher-RouteMatcher) that specifies the query part of the request. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65118396/how-can-we-ignore-the-openhash-value-in-cy-route-request-send/65136063#65136063) for an example. Of course, you would add two intercepts which differ by the query parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is indeed a much cleaner solution to come up with and it seems to have solve my problem. Could you maybe answer the post so I can validate your answer as a solution to this question ?

Comment: No problem. The key:value pair of the query needs to be known  - obviously the value is the typed text, but key is not apparent above. Perhaps you can add an answer, and show the full url as logged by the interception.